# mybatis @insert reruns batch update

Tags: mysql, mybatis, batch-updates

I am trying to run a custom sql on a batch session object

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO ticker(Ticker, GetUpdate) VALUES(#{symbol}, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE GetUpdate = 1")
void enableQuoteforSymbol(@Param("symbol") String symbol);
```

but my following code, which is responsible for flushing and committing the batches have some mysterious behavior

```
while(true == continueProcessing.get())
{
    List<BatchResult> batchResult;
    try 
    {
        batchResult = batchSqlSession.flushStatements();

        if(batchResult.size() > 0 )
        {
            batchSqlSession.commit();
            batchSqlSession.clearCache();
        }

        Thread.sleep(configurationManager.BATCH_COMMITER_DELAY);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        logger.error("BatchService::run() - ", ex);
    }
}
```

it executes perfectly and batchSqlSession.flushStatements() does give back number of executed statements. Despite of successful execution of previous batch, this code **batchResult = batchSqlSession.flushStatements();** and **batchSqlSession.commit();** reruns the same old batch in next iteration. why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug:
http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=695

Aready fixed for the next version.